# ¿Porque me arroja el siguiente error al clickear en la tabla de mi jFrame?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

Basicamente programe una vista en la cual yo pudiera ingresar datos, modificar, elminar, de tal manera que si yo clickeaba en la tabla esta me dejaria modificar los datos que yo desee, el problema es que me arroja un error que no comprendo y esto no me deja seguir adelante.

Adjunto el error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   10    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)     at
>   Sistema.Arriendobiblioteca.jTable1MouseClicked(Arriendobiblioteca.java:981)
>     at Sistema.Arriendobiblioteca.access$400(Arriendobiblioteca.java:16)
>     at
>   Sistema.Arriendobiblioteca$5.mouseClicked(Arriendobiblioteca.java:177)
>     at
>   java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)

voy a la linea 981 de mi codigo que es segun el netbeans la que me esta ocasionando este problema.

Adjuntare esa parte del codigo para que me puedan comprender:

```
private void tbuscarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
            String campo = this.tbuscar.getText();
    try {
        ConexionBD nuevos = new ConexionBD();
        Statement st = nuevos.conn.createStatement();

        String comando ="select count(*) from arriendo "
                + "inner join libros  on  arriendo.Libros_idLibros=libros.idLibros"
                + " where Libros_arriendo like '" + campo + "%'"
                + " or titulo_libro like '%" + campo + "%'"
                + " or Fecha_arriendo like '" + campo + "%'"
                + " or Fecha_devolucion like '%" + campo + "%'"
                + " or Fecha_entrega like '" + campo + "%'"
                + " or Costo_arriendo like '%" + campo + "%'"
                + " order by idArriendo asc";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(comando);
        this.jTable1.setModel(nuevos.consultaArriendo(campo));


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}                                   

private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    int seleccion = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());


    tcosto.setText(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 5)));
    nomArriendo.setText(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 0)));



    String fechaArridia, fechaArrimes, fechaArrian;
    String fechaEntdia, fechaEntmes, fechaEntan;
    String fechaDevdia, fechaDevmes, fechaDevan;


    fechaArrimes = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 1)).substring(3, 5);
    boxmes.setSelectedItem(fechaArrimes);

    fechaArridia = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 1)).substring(0, 2);
    boxdia.setSelectedItem(fechaArridia);

    fechaArrian = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 1)).substring(6, 10);
    boxan.setSelectedItem(fechaArrian);



    fechaEntmes = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 4)).substring(14, 16);
    boxenmes.setSelectedItem(fechaEntmes);
    fechaEntdia = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 4)).substring(11, 13);
    boxendia.setSelectedItem(fechaEntdia);
    fechaEntan = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 4)).substring(17, 21);
    boxenan.setSelectedItem(fechaEntan);


    fechaDevmes = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 6)).substring(25, 27);
    boxdevmes.setSelectedItem(fechaDevmes);
    fechaDevdia = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 6)).substring(22, 24);
    boxdevdia.setSelectedItem(fechaDevdia);
    fechaDevan = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 6)).substring(28, 32);
    boxdevan.setSelectedItem(fechaDevan);


    combolibro.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 3)));



    try {

        ConexionBD nuevos = new ConexionBD();
        Statement st = nuevos.conn.createStatement();

        String comando = "Select * from libros";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(comando);

        while (rs.next()) {


            combolibro.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("idLibros") + "   " + String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 2)));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }



    this.bcrear.setEnabled(false);
    this.bmodificar.setEnabled(true);
    this.beliminar.setEnabled(true);           // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Los "box..." ese es el nombre que reciben los botones de mis vistas tengo 3 fechas diferentes con nombres distintos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está aquí

```
fechaArrian = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 1)).substring(6, 10);
```

Estas haciendo un substring desde la posicion 6 hasta la 10 (no inclusive) de un String que como máximo tiene 9 de longitud.

Comment: Ahh muchas gracias, lo analizare con mas profundidad soy nuevos en jFrame asi que mejorare para no cometer estos errores :)

Comment: De todas formas hay algo que no entendi ¿como infieres que solo tiene maximo de 8 de longitud?

Comment: Perdon, no es 8 si no 9. Ya lo edite. La razon por la que se que es de maximo 9 es porque lo indica el error `String index out of range: 10`. Eso te dice que estas intentando acceder a la posición 10 de un String y esta no existe por lo que como máximo tendra 9

Comment: Agradesco la ayuda, pero estoy intentando modificar para que todo funcione pero redusco ese rango y me lanza el mismo error pero esta vez con menos tamaño es decir pongo 7 y me termina diciendo que el maximo sera hasta la 6 ;(

Comment: ¿Que contiene ese String?

Comment: una fecha asi como por ejemplo "10-05-2012"

Comment: No creo que tenga que utilizar algo de tipo date, si ya me funciono en otras vistas el problema es que no se porque no me esta funcionando con estos combobox de fechas.

Comment: No puede ser, si vale "10-05-2012" el `substring(6,10)` deberia funcionar. Revisa que tenga ese valor

Comment: di vuelta el codigo, lo probe muchas veces y me sigue tirando el mismo error, seguire buscando de todas formas y esperemos tambien a que alguien mas venga a dar su opinion ;)

Comment: Ya lo solucione, jure que la fecha tenia "-" "-" "-" pero estaba con "/" y tenia una coma en donde no debia pero aun asi no me salia como error, pero gracias por la ayuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

El error está en:

> String index out of range: 10

Probablemente el dato de donde quieres hacer el substring no tiene esa longitud, por lo tanto al no existir dicho puntero dentro de la memoria marca un error.